# Transfer data from one sheet to multiple if A1 matches with data in the sheet with list

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have around 20-30 sheets that are created each day, they all begin with a name in A1, like "Pamela Anderson", I want the script to find the matching text in the sheet called "List" and add in cell B1 whatever is in the cell next to "Pamela Anderson" in the list sheet.

The list starts from A3 and down to B35 at the most. If the name isn't in the list it shouldn't add any data to B1 at all.

So, if in "random sheetname" in cell A1 it says "Barrack" and in the list A5 has "Barrack" and B5 has "Obama", it should copy B5 info to "random sheetname" and paste it in B1. The script should search all sheets and add the data if possible.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, listSht As Worksheet
    Dim listRng As Range, found As Range

    Set listSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    With listSht
        Set listRng = .Range("A3:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'sets the list range dowwn to the last non empty cell in column "A" of "List" sheet
    End With
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> listSht.Name Then
            Set found = listRng.Find(what:=sht.Range("A1").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then found.Offset(, 1).Copy Destination:=sht.Range("B1")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change cell ranges for value, result and lookup range in the method below

```
Sub LookupMac()
'
' LookupMac Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'

  Dim lookupRange As Range
  Dim result As Variant
  Dim lookupValue
  lookupValue = Range("A1")

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        Set lookupRange = wks.Range("A5:B35")
        result = Application.VLookup(lookupValue, lookupRange, 2, False)
        If IsError(result) Then
            'result = ""
            Range("B1").Value = ""
        Else
            'MsgBox (result & " found in " & wks.Name)
            Range("B1").Value = result
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```